# Dividing between two text UI field value in UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is two text UI fields with numeric values. I also have a Button.

How can I do something like this:

After pushing the button:

1. Devide value of `Textfield1` by 10
2. `TextField2` gets the value of `Textfield1`

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get the `text` value of an [`InputField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html)

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference those in the inspector via drag and drop
    public InputField Textfield1;
    public InputField Textfield2;

    public void DevideByTen()
    {
        float num1;

        // Tries to parse the inserted string value into a float value
        // if wrong input or bad format this returns 0 instead of throwing an exception
        float.TryParse(Textfield1.text, num1);

        // if instead you prefer to explicitly throw an exception 
        // you could do something like
        try
        {
            num1 = float.Parse(Textfield1.text);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogWarningFormat(this, "Could not parse input: \"{0}\"", Textfield1.text);
            Debug.LogException(e);
            return;
        }

        // Devide by 10
        var devided = num1 / 10.0f;

        // Set the result of the deviding as text to Textfield2
        Textfield2.text = devided.ToString();
    }
}
```

In the buttons `onClick` reference the `DevideByTen` method (or how you want to call it).

---

Note that in `ToString()` you can also pass a rule how the number should be displayed. let's say

```
float num1 = 1.12344;
```

than e.g.

```
num1.ToString("00.00")   =>  "01.12"
num1.ToString("##.###")  =>  "1.123"
num1.ToString("P")       =>  "112.34 %"
...
```

See e.g. [ToString(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?view=netframework-4.6#System_Decimal_ToString_System_String_) for more information on that and [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?view=netframework-4.6) for a complete list of available standard values.

Comment: Value in TextField1 get from another script

Comment: what do you mean? Can you explain a bit further?

Comment: I have IOS plug-in and script that return my Pulse number for example 65 and put it in TextField1. So then I need to divide this number on 10, and then put result (6 or 7 if number is rounded off) in TextField2 by pushing Button

Comment: as soon as you get the value into the `TextField1.text` value from that plug-in there is no problem. Simply drag the according InputFields into the `Textfield1` and `Textfield2` fields in the inspector. I updated the script according to your comment

Comment: Thx a lot derHugo

Comment: @AxelVipovski Glad to help :)